# Looking for a general and complete solution to the Diophantine $a^2 -2b^4 = -1$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

The general and probably complete solution to $a^2+(b-1)^2 = (b)^2 is (2v+1)^2+(2v(v+1))^2 = (v^2+(v+1)^2)^2$ We get the triples $(a,b-1,b) = (3,4,5), (5,12,13), (7,24,5^2),...,(41,840,29^2),...,(239,28560,13^4),...$

If we only want those b that are also squares, we must solve the Pell like equation $a^2 -2b^2 =-1$ whose $(a,b)$ solutions beginning with the trivial $(1,1)$ are $(7,5), (41,29), (239,13^2),...$
given by the recurrent relation :$ a(n+1) = 3a(n) + 4b(n); b(n+1) = 2a(n) + 3b(n)$. What is the general solution, if known, to $a^2 -2b^4 = -1 $?

Comment: The general theory says it will have only finitely many solutions.

Comment: Why did you edit me , mister Gerry Myerson, so shortly after i published my question? What are you doing without my consentment for such a insufficient answer?

Comment: I edited you because you don't know how to spell "diophantine". If you don't like being edited without consent, you've come to the wrong website. And that's *Doctor* Myerson to you.

Comment: Always be scared by strong personalities, Mister Myerson. I am not suffering though from a lack of knowledge but from some kind of dislexia when i write fast; sorry Doctor.

Comment: Apology accepted. Anyway, you can see the edit history by clicking on the time/date/whatever next to the word, "edited"; you'll find someone else did most of the editing, and it was done to improve the formatting (to make a^2 look like $a^2$, for example). Regular users are *encouraged* to do this type of editing.

Comment: Well Gerry; so you´re editing people not because they do not say the truth but cause you do not like the way they aesthetic (1).

Comment: If you have a problem with editing, flag it for moderator attention. But I think you will find that editing for aesthetics and spelling is considered a good thing here.

Comment: I had no time to complete my meaning;Well Gerry; so you´re editing people not because they do not say the truth but cause you do not like the way they aesthetic (1). (1): i know aesthetic is not a verb. But the way you represent (that is you write; that is you draw/design) the representation of a power is just that, only a matter of aesthetic.

Comment: And the difference between to aesthetic and to ethic is that to asethetic is much more a matter of non-objectivity; a arbitrary matter; the contrary of what should define mathematics:             the-language-that-is-not-arbitrary and thus transcends other universalist representations.

Comment: "other universalist representations" are languages; like Spanish or French or English; that is commoly spoken and written main -and also minority- languages. Mathematics is a kind of written  language of languages without the ability to be spoken; you need a delay and thus write it.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. I repeat: if you have a problem with the editing that Elias and I did, flag your question for moderator attention.

Comment: Philosophy began this way; Gerry. Once upon a time, long ago, someone thought he had no idea of something and said it as you´ve done here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mordell, Diophantine Equations, page 271, writes, "...for the special case $$y^2=2x^4-1$$ it has been known for two centuries that solutions are given by $(x,y)=(1,1)$ and $(13,239)$. It was proved by Ljunggren that these are the only positive integer solutions. The proof is exceedingly complicated." Mordell gives the citation, Zur Theorie der Gleichung $x^2+1=Dy^4$, Avh. Norske Vid. Akad. Oslo No. 5 1 (1942).

Guy, Unsolved Problems In Number Theory, 3rd edition, Problem D6 is "An elementary solution of $x^2=2y^4-1$." Guy cites Steiner and Tzanakis, Simplifying the solution of Ljunggren's equation $X^2+1=2Y^4$, J Number Theory 37 (1991) 123-132, and writes, "Whether Steiner & Tzanakis have simplified the solution may be a matter of taste; they use the theory of linear forms in logarithms of algebraic numbers."

Guy also cites a proof by Chen Jian-Hua, which he calls "unconventional." The bibliographic details are, A new solution of the Diophantine equation $X^2+1=2Y^4$, J Number Theory 48 (1994) 62-74 and A note on the Diophantine equation $x^2+1=dy^4$, Abh. Math. Sem. Univ. Hamburg 64 (1994) 1-10.

I'd suggest also looking at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WIlhelm_Ljunggren) on Ljunggren.

And there's more: Konstantinos A. Draziotis, The Ljunggren equation revisited, Colloq. Math. 109 (2007), no. 1, 9–11.

Michael A. Bennett, Irrationality via the hypergeometric method, Diophantine analysis and related fields—DARF 2007/2008, 7–18, AIP Conf. Proc., 976, Amer. Inst. Phys., Melville, NY, 2008.

Comment: Thanks for the good information, Gerry. I did not know it. We can then deduce almost immediately (am i wrong?) hat the equation a^4 -2b^4 = -1 has no integer non trivial solutions since 239 is not a square. I would be interested in knowing all the solutions, if there are, to a^2 - 2b^2n = -1 or alternatively to know all the solutions to a^2n - 2b^2 = -1 with the intention of proving a^2n - 2b^2n = -1 has no non trivial solutions. I believe, but could be wrong, proving a^(2n+1) - 2b^(2n+1) = -1 has no non trivial solutions  might be harder.

Comment: Now here's where aesthetics becomes mathematics. You write, b^2n. How is one to know whether you mean $b^{2n}$ or $b^2n$? If you plan to use this site regularly, please do yourself and others a favor, and learn a little about how to use TeX to format your mathematics here.

Comment: You are half right, i am half wrong here. I should have put parenthesis; or brackets, i am not sure of the sense you give north by northwest (seen from where i´m living and belong to, this old and southerener Europe  we love) to parenthesis: b^(2n). Furthermore i should have written b^(2*n) and 2*b^(2*n) to avoid any confusion (2b and 2n could be  variables distinct from b and from n), but i was too lazy. I am an amateur and never used TeX, but i´ll try next time.

Comment: Yet if you edit somebody to change the meaning of what he/she  wrote, this seems to me less acceptable and near to censorship, even though the intention was good, to put it better and with a better style. But i think all is OK now.

Comment: for(v=1,10^10,if(issquare((v^2+(v+1)^2),&n)&ispower(n),print([v,n])))
[119, 169] time = 3h, 7min, 887 ms.
 This maldroit very short program in Pari gp

Comment: for(v=1,10^10,if(issquare((v^2+(v+1)^2),&n)&ispower(n),print([v,n])))
[119, 169] time = 3h, 7min, 887 ms.
 This maladroit very short program written in Pari gp shows experimentally there are no integer solutions to               a^2 -2*b^(2*n) = -1 up to around 10^10. Sorry for the repetition but your web-scripts do not give me enough time (5 mn only) to edit; not enough when you´re working in real time.

Comment: And this : for(v=1,10^10,if(issquare((v^2+(v+1)^2),&n)&ispower(2*v+1),print(v))) time = 2h, 22min, 42,349 ms. (nothing found)
shows experimentally, if i did not mess somewhere, that the equation a^n -2*b^2 = -1 has no integer solution less than 2*10^10.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be long sorry.

Diophantine equation a^2 - 2b^4 = -1 is a special case of the more general equation known as the negative Pell equation, x^2 - dy^2 = -1, where d is a positive integer that is not a perfect square. In this case, we have d = 2.

To find the fundamental solution to the equation x^2 - 2y^2 = -1, we can use the continued fraction expansion of sqrt(2). The continued fraction expansion of sqrt(2) is [1; 2, 2, 2, ...], which can be written as the infinite continued fraction

sqrt(2) = 1 + 1/(2 + 1/(2 + 1/(2 + ...)))

If we truncate this continued fraction after n terms, we get a rational number P_n/Q_n that is a convergent of sqrt(2). The convergents have the property that

|P_n^2 - 2Q_n^2| = (-1)^n

In particular, if n is odd, then P_n^2 - 2Q_n^2 = -1. Therefore, the fundamental solution to the equation x^2 - 2y^2 = -1 is given by the odd convergent P_n/Q_n of sqrt(2), where n is the smallest odd integer such that P_n is positive.

In this case, we have

sqrt(2) = [1; 2, 2, 2, ...] = 1 + 1/(2 + 1/(2 + 1/(2 + ...)))

The first few convergents are:

P_1/Q_1 = 1/1
P_3/Q_3 = 7/5
P_5/Q_5 = 41/29
P_7/Q_7 = 239/169

We see that P_3 is positive, so the fundamental solution is (x,y) = (7,5).

To generate all solutions to the equation x^2 - 2y^2 = -1, we can use the fact that the solutions form an infinite sequence given by

(x_n + y_n*sqrt(2))^k

where k is a positive integer and (x_n, y_n) is the nth solution to the equation. In this case, we have (x_1, y_1) = (7,5).

Therefore, the general solution to the Diophantine equation a^2 - 2b^4 = -1 is given by

a + b^2sqrt(2) = (7 + 5sqrt(2))^k

for some positive integer k. We can find explicit formulas for a and b in terms of k using the binomial theorem:

a = (7^k + 5sqrt(2)^k)^2
b = (27^k*5^(k-1))^1/4

Therefore, for each positive integer k, we get a solution to the original equation.